# All of the RNNs I see in educational materials have only one layer, why is that?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

For example

http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/

Can RNN's only have one layer for some reason? Or do these examples just use one layer to simplify the concept?

Comment: Because these are all tutorials. Real applications are multi-layered, such as NMT - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the answer. There are instances where deep layers are possible, but since the temporal aspects already add computational complexity, usually only a few layers are used.

I learned this Andrew Ng's deep learning course, the section on sequence models.